# Redirect country script not working

Tags: php, redirect, geo

I want a little help with this

First, I downloaded MaxMind's GeoIP.dat database from here

Then I downloaded geoip.inc from here

Then I uploaded those two files to the same directory where my page is located.

I edited my php page and wrote this script inside of it:

```
<?php
require_once('geoip.inc');

$gi = geoip_open('GeoIP.dat', GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE);
 $country = geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
geoip_close($gi);

$my_countries = array('us', 'ca', 'gb', 'fr', 'de', 'nl');
if (!in_array(strtolower($country), $my_countries))
{
header('Location: http://"ALL"TRAFFICURLGOESHERE.whatever');
}
else
{
header('Location: http://"SELECTEDCOUNTRIES"URLGOESHERE.whatever');
}
?>
```

AND THIS WAS WORKING GREAT !

BUT

I want something like this :

- Country A users redirect to W url
- Country B users redirect to X url
- Country C users redirect to Y url
- Country D users redirect to Z url

And remaining country users redirects to the same URL that I want.

Can anyone please edit this php code with like 2-3 countries examples to different URLs and remaining to other URL that I want so that I can learn how to add more other (more than 4 country) countries to that code because I am really not good at php or html.

I TRIED THIS (the below code) ALSO BUT THAT WAS NOT WORKING

```
<?php
 require_once('geoip.inc');
$gi = geoip_open('GeoIP.dat', GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE);
$country = geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
geoip_close($gi);
$my_countries = 'us';
if (strtolower($country) == $my_countries) {
header('Location: example.us');
}
$my_countriess = 'nz';
if (strtolower($country) == $my_countriess) {
header('Location: example.co.nz);
}
$my_countriesss = 'uk';
if (strtolower($country) == $my_countriesss) {
header('Location: example.co.uk');
}
$my_countriessss = 'ca';
if (strtolower($country) == $my_countriessss) {
header('Location: example.ca');
}
?>
```

Comment: you have a syntax error where you are missing an ending single quote on line: header('Location: example.co.nz);

Answer (score 0):

> I want something like this: Country A users redirect to W url... And remaining country users redirects to the same URL that I want.

Since you're new to PHP, it sounds like you want to use a series of simple `if` statements?

```
if ($country === "us"){
    // redirect to US
} else if ($country === "nz"){
    // redirect to nz
} else if ($country === "..."){
    // continue specifically targeting country codes
} else {
    // redirect to everywhere else if none of the above match
}
```

As you picked up on, you may need to use `strtolower()` so that the strings will match.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `switch ... case` for that.

Example:

```
switch ($country) {
     case 'us':
         $location = 'USURL';
         break;
     case 'uk':
         $location = 'UK URL';
         break;
     case ...
     ...
     default:
         $location = 'other countries url';
         break;
}
header('Location: $location');
```

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php for more informations about the `switch` statement

Edit:
By the way in your second code an semicolon is missing:

```
header('Location: example.co.nz);
```

should be

```
header('Location: example.co.nz');
```

Comment: I know that when I started learning PHP, `switch` and `case` looked scary to me.